# Problems building a cordova android app on mac

Tags: android, macos, cordova, ant

I'm having problems getting my Cordova app to build on my Mac running El Capitan.

I've downloaded and installed **JDK-8u73-macosx-x64.dmg** and **android-studio-ide-141.2456560-mac.dmg** which seem like they are the latest versions available.

I've ran Android studio and got it to download the Android SDK (basically whatever's checked to install by default)

I've also installed Ant via Homebrew (brew install ant)

- Ant is installed at /usr/local/bin/ant
- Java is installed at /usr/bin/java
- Android SDK is installed at /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk

I've created a .bash_profile file at ~/.bash_profile which contains the following:

```
# JAVA
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

# ANT
export ANT_HOME=$(/usr/local/bin/ant)

# Export to PATH
export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${ANT_HOME}/bin
```

When I run cordova build android I get the following error:

```
admins-Mac-mini:Swipii admin$ cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:599)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:566)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:563)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:562)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:559)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:109)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:98)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:504)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:83)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/admin/Documents/Swipii/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 128

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> No match found

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.385 secs
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: /Users/admin/Documents/Swipii/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/admin/Documents/Swipii/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: Error code 1 for command: /Users/admin/Documents/Swipii/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/admin/Documents/Swipii/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
admins-Mac-mini:Swipii admin$
```

I think my .bash_profile file isn't correct but not sure why?

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I've had also this issue. It dissapeared after including "**android:versionCode="310**" in the manifest tag of the **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

I had previously removed it because Andoid Studio was sending a message (*This versionCode value (310) is not used. It is always overrriden by...* ) that it overruled whatever you write there, as, infact, it was doing. But in the end, not placing it prevented the app from being built.

The final resul of my manifest tag was:

```
<manifest android:installLocation="auto"  android:versionCode="310" android:versionName="3.1" package="xxx.mypackage" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

I hope it helps.